# Upload failed (403): Invalid or non-existent authentication information: Python

Tags: python

I am trying to distribute a sample package.
I am following the below mentioned steps:

1) `python.exe setup.py register`

Here I decide to use the existing login and provide my username and pssaword. I get this message:

[image]

2) `python.exe setup.py sdist upload`

But when I fire this I get the above mentioned error in the summary.
[image]

This is my directory structure
[image]

I am following the steps as mentioned in Head First Python book.
Can some one please guide me? Am I missing some step?

I am also uploading my contents of my setup file.
[image]

**NOTE: I am a beginner in python and have just started learning it.**

Answer (score 8):

`python setup.py register` and `python setup.py upload` are [deprecated](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi). Do *not* use them.

Follow the instructions in the [Python Packaging Guide](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/):

1. Create an account on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/account/register/) if you haven't yet.
2. Create the source distribution and wheels for your package: `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`
3. Install [twine](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#twine) (or make sure you have version 2.0 or newer): `pip install twine`
4. Check your distribution files for errors: `twine check dist/*`
5. (Optional) [Upload to the PyPI test server](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-testpypi/#using-test-pypi) first (note: separate user registration required): `twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*`
6. Upload to PyPI: `twine upload dist/*`

To save typing your PyPI credentials, create `$HOME/.pypirc` with the following contents:

```
[pypi]
username = <username>
password = <password>
```

> Note: your password will be stored in plain text!

Comment: You can test a package uploaded to the test serving with `python3 -m pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ <packagename>`